# Find class, add class to parent (li)

Tags: jquery, css

I have some code that is generated by some Javascript (I don't want to adjust that, it's huge!). As a workaround, I can achieve what I want with Jquery and CSS, just not sure how to go about it.

I have several bullet points, I want to find all the span's with the class `bubble-lorem`, I then want to add a class to the parent `li` called `price`. I think Jquery does this but not sure how to achieve it.

The second part of the question, once it's added the class `price` to all the correct `li`'s, I want to add a class `clear` to the next `li` after it. So for example if there was 3 `<li class="price">` in a row, I want to find the next `li` after the last `<li class="price">` and add a class to that?

```
<li>
    <span style="margin-left: 0px; width: 240px;" class="bubble bubble-default" data-duration="18"></span>
    <span class="date">01/2015-12/2016</span>
    <span class="label">Phase 1</span>
</li>

<li>
    <span style="margin-left: 30px; width: 30px;" class="bubble bubble-lorem" data-duration="2"></span>
    <span class="date">04/2015-06/2015</span>
    <span class="label">£0.8</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your requests can be achieved with one-liners:

```
$('.bubble-lorem').closest('li').addClass('price');
$('.price').next('li:not(.price)').addClass('clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part I:** You need to use `:has` selector:

```
$('li:has(.bubble-lorem)').addClass('price');
```

**Part II:**

```
$('.price').next('li:not(.price)').addClass('clear');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwsenut4/)**

Comment: You don't want this... just use class selector.

Answer (score 0):

For part one of your question:

```
// This finds all elements with 'bubble-lorem' class and 
// adds 'price' class to their parents
$( ".bubble-lorem" ).parent().addClass( "price" );
```

For second part of your question:

```
// This finds the elements with 'price' class whose next li does not have 
// 'price' class (which will be the last element) and adds 'clear' class to it
$('.price').next('li:not(.price)').addClass('clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.bubble-lorem').parent('li').addClass('price');
$('.price').last().next().addClass('clear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

```
$("span.bubble-lorem").parent().addClass('price');
```

Answer 2:

```
$("li.price").next().addClass('clear');
```